# Where does TextMate2 store the icons it uses to represent specific file-types?

Tags: macos, icons, textmate

When you save a TextMate 2 document with a `.py` extension the window's title acquires a *Python* icon that I've only ever seen in TextMate:

[image]

Does anyone know where this icon, and the icons associated with other file-types  are kept? I can't find then in the TextMate 2 GitHub repository, they don't appear to be in the application's package, and I've not been able to locate any of them using `mdfind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to `TextMate.app/Contents/Resources` to find all icon files. You can find the icons used on the following GitHub [repository](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/tree/master/Frameworks/OakAppKit/icons). Some other icons also come from their respective installation folders.

Comment: Excellent! I thought I'd checked all the relevant folders in that repository - clearly not.